# Publish multiple consecutive messages to RabbitMQ exchange

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Is it possible to publish multiple messages to a RabbitMQ exchange in a way that they'll be processed consecutivly, ie there won't be messages originated somewhere else being processed between my messages.

If there is, what is the RMQ Java API for that?

Comment: afaik, it is not possible. Even with [transaction](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html) the atomicity on a single queue is not garantee.

Answer (score 0):

If you need items to be processed in the same order how about putting them all in a single message to be processed by a single consumer?

Even if you could tell rabbit "process these in order" there could be many rabbit consumers attached so message #2 might get done processing before message #1.